# Apache nifi and pentaho port issue

Tags: apache, pentaho, apache-nifi, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-cde

Both Apache nifi and Pentaho uses the same port. When I start the pentaho services. Unable to open the UI. ( http://localhost:8080/pentaho ). Receiving the error message as 
"
Did you mean: /nifi
You may have mistyped...
"
Please assist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the NiFi side, there is a property `nifi.web.http.port` in conf/nifi.properties that specifies the HTTP port to open for NiFi, and it defaults to 8080. You can change it to something else and restart NiFi. For example, change it to 8989 and then you can access NiFi at http://localhost:8989/nifi.